# PHP how to round decimal numbers

Tags: php, decimal

how to round decimals which could look like that:

for example:

```
if decimals range from 0.26 to 0.74 I need to round to 0.50
if decimals range from 0.75 to 1.25 I need to round to 1.00
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not use if statements?

Comment: Maybe there is more simple way than if statements ? And how you can achieve this with if statements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function customRound($number) {

    // extract integer part out of the number
    $int_part = (int)$number;

    // extract decimal part
    $dec_part = (float)($number - $int_part);

    $dec_rounded = 0;
    if ($dec_part >= 0.26 && $dec_part < 0.75 ) {
        $dec_rounded = 0.5;
    } elseif ($dec_part >= 0.75) {
        $dec_rounded = 1.0;
    }

    return $int_part + $dec_rounded;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madhur, you did a great job. Just fix "$int)part" to "$int_part". It will be usefull for others too!

Answer (score 0):

I let here an alternative example:

```
function customRound($number)
{
    // Extract integer part out of the number.
    $int_part = (int)$number;

    // Extract decimal part from the number.
    $dec_part = (float)($number - $int_part);

    // Make the custom round on the decimal part.
    $dec_rounded = $dec_part >= 0.75 ? 1.0 : ($dec_part >= 0.26 ? 0.5 : 0.0);

    return $int_part + $dec_rounded;
}
```